# How can I pass values from 1 fragment to another with Bundle()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I found this code to pass the data from a fragment to another:

Fragment 1:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", data);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Fragment 2:

```
   Bundle bundle = getArguments();
   assert bundle != null;
   String data = bundle.getString("data");
```

But I dont want to change the fragment. So I removed parts of it. But it doesnt work. Here my code:

Fragment 1:

```
public void openActifity2(){
    Fragment_score fragment_score = new Fragment_score();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", finishedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("FAILED_LEVELS", failedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("SKIPPED_LEVELS", skippedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("USED_HINTS", usedHints);
    fragment_score.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    int finishedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS");
    int failedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS");
    int skippedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS");
    int usedHints = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS");
```

Do I have to use the code I found on the internet or does my version work too?
I get this error when I open the second fragment:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz, PID: 20931
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz.Fragment_score.onCreateView(Fragment_score.java:26)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)

Comment: if you're using MVVM design pattern you can easily use viewmodel to share data between your fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to avoid getting the error, try this

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle != null){
    int finishedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
    int failedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
    int skippedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
    int usedHints = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
}
```

Based on your comments, you can change fragment in `onOptionsItemSelected` method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_1) {
        // add your action here that you want
        return true;
    }else if (id==R.id.action_2) {
         // add your action here that you want
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I open the 2nd fragment with a sidebar menu.

Comment: My sidebar menu: https://youtu.be/USenYOBJw9Y Part 1/4.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the fragments than your code will be working fine. But if you don't want to change fragments than  1)  `int finishedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", 0);` OR 2) Instead of bundle use static global variables     `public static int finishedLevels = 0;` in *Fragment 1* and then simply get their value in *Fragment 2* using class name reference.
**Note:** If you don't want to change the fragment and want values in *Fragment 2* then i would recommend the **static variables**